# Unable to obtain php variable using ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a php file with a variable $consult_id obtained from DB as follows:

```
$consult_id = $row['consult_id'];
```

The same php file **includes at the bottom another file 2** which includes both php and JavaScript. The relevant code is:

```
$http({
method: 'get',
url: 'inc/token.inc.php'
}).then(function(response) {
//alert(response);
data = JSON.parse(response);
```

The **token.inc.php** file referenced in the above code in **file 2** is as follows:

```
$apiObj = new MYAPI(API_KEY, API_SECRET);
$sessId = $consult_id;
$connectionData = $name; 
$token = $apiObj->generateToken($sessionId , array(
    'data'       => $connectionData
));
$dresponseData = array(
        'sessionId' => trim($sessId),
        'token'=>trim($token)
    );

echo json_encode($dresponseData);
```

If i hardcode the string in the following it works perfectly:

```
$sessId = XXXXXXXXXX; //insead of $consult_id
```

I tried the following and lot other things without success:

```
$sessId = json_encode($consult_id,JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

The $sessId always gives **null**

I know it has something to do with "ajax and php" but being a newbie could not identify the issue.

Hardcoding the string works fine.

Comment: $consult_id is undefined in the other php file.
You need to use the "data" parameter for the ajax request function, so you'd be able to pass the consult_id variable's value to the other php file.

Comment: @OfirBaruch $consult_id is defined and tried echoing it with success.

Comment: 1. enable proper PHP error reporting, 2. check what the script has actually returned by inspecting the AJAX request in your browser dev tools, network tab.

Comment: Ammm... nope. "If i hardcode the string in the following it works perfectly" but when not - "The $sessId always gives null".

Comment: The browser dev tools showed value as null. Error reporting too is enabled.

Comment: _"$consult_id is defined and tried echoing it with success"_ - no it is not, and no you did not try that with success - __not in__ `token.inc.php`, because that has absolutely nothing to do with your other script. You are making a separate HTTP request here, so that is the same as if you called `token.inc.php` directly via your browser address bar. Of course in that case you would not expect it to know any `$consult_id` variable, so don't make that mistake now just because the request is made via AJAX instead.

Comment: @CBroe What i meant was i hardcoded the $sessId in token.inc.php to test it and whether all other files depending on it works.. But $consult_id is not getting pulled from file 1. So do i need to make an ajax request from token.inc.php to get $consult_id.

Comment: Of course it works when you hard-code it inside the script itself. _"So do i need to make an ajax request from token.inc.php to get $consult_id."_ - no, the other way around. The first file you mentioned is the one you load directly in your browser, correct? And from there - the client side - you want to get a token from some API? Then you need to make the AJAX request _to_ `token.inc.php`. But because that script knows nothing of your `$consult_id` variable, you must pass the value to it in the HTTP request you are making - as a GET or POST parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `token.inc.php` file is a separated file.
The variable `$consult_id` is being defined in another file so even if you have an ajax request - it's doesn't relate to the php's variable's **scope**.

If you'd include the token.inc file with PHP command (like: `include/require`) - then, it would be possible to access that variable.

What you need to do is to use the `data` parameter in your ajax request (as I've suggested in the comment) and pass that variable to the other file.

**JS:**

```
$http({
method: 'post', //changed to post
data: {consultId: '<?php echo $consult_id; ?>'}, //added the 'data' parameter
url: 'inc/token.inc.php'
}).then(function(response) {
```

**In the token.inc.php file:**

```
$sessID = $_POST['consultId'];
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this and understand it.

Comment: Not working. Nothing is getting POSTED in developer tools ??

Comment: This code should work. Consider uploading a demo so we'll be able to debug and analyse what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry..I am working offline
I tried this too:
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'inc/token.inc.php',
    data: "consult_sess=" + '<?php echo $consult_id; ?>',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).then(function(response) {

Comment: Thanks for the help. I resolved it in a different way using php sessions.